# What is stereo about multi-view stereo?

Tags: 3d, depth-map, photometric, scene-description

What 3D scene reconstruction methods does the term "multi-view stereo" encompass? Is it only used for methods that apply binocular stereo algorithms (taking 2 views as input) in a pairwise manner? Or only methods based on disparity estimation? If not why is the term "stereo" used?

Comment: Where have you seen that term? Stereo 3D reconstruction is a special case of multi-view reconstruction as far as I know. I have never seen the term "multi-view stereo".

Comment: For example http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1153518

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Multi-view stereo (MVS) is the general term
> given to a group of techniques that use stereo correspondence as their
> main cue and use more than two images.

A quote from ['Multi-View Stereo: A Tutorial'](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/%7Efurukawa/papers/fnt_mvs.pdf) by Yasutaka Furukawa and Carlos Hernández.

So to paraphrase: We have a set of images that is larger than two, and use them in a pairwise manner by applying techniques that finde stereo correspondences to reconstruct the object shown in them.

If you want to know more about MVS algorithms that paper I linked seems to be pretty good and at least Furukawa is a name that I know and have read papers from, so he seems to know the topic.